# How to pass data from child component to parent component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am currently learning React, and I am trying to build a small weatherapp to practice with apis, axios and react generally. I built an input component where it's duty is getting the data from the API, and I am holding the data in the useState hook and I want to use the data in the main App component? I am able to pass data from parent App component to input component if I take the functionality in the app component, but this time I start to have problems with input text rendering problems. Here is the code:
this is the input component where I search and get the data from the API, and I am trying to pass the weatherData into the main App component and render it there. How is it possible to achieve this?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const key = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;

function SearchLocation() {
  const [text, textChange] = useState('');
  const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState([]);

  const handleText = (e) => {
    textChange(e.target.value);
  };

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json`,
      {
        params: {
          key: key,
          q: text,
          lang: 'en',
        },
      }
    );
    setWeatherData(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      fetchData();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [text]);
  console.log(weatherData);
  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input
          onChange={handleText}
          className="locationInput"
          type="text"
          value={text}
          required
        ></input>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
export default SearchLocation;
```

EDIT:

After moving the states to main component and passing them to children as props I receive 3 errors, GET 400 error from the API, createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400 and textChange is not a function error. Here are how components look like. This is the input component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const key = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;

function SearchLocation({ weatherData, setWeatherData, text, textChange }) {
  const handleText = (e) => {
    textChange(e.target.value);
  };

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json`,
      {
        params: {
          key: key,
          q: text,
          lang: 'en',
        },
      }
    );
    setWeatherData(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      fetchData();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [text]);
  console.log(weatherData);
  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input
          onChange={handleText}
          className="locationInput"
          type="text"
          value={text}
          required
        ></input>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
export default SearchLocation;
```

this is the parent app component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import './index.css';
import SearchLocation from './components/Input';

function App() {
  const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState([]);
  const [text, textChange] = useState('');
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SearchLocation
        setWeatherData={setWeatherData}
        lastData={weatherData}
        inputText={text}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll still need to store the state in the parent component. Pass the setter down as a prop. This is a React pattern called [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Example:

```
const App = () => {
  const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState([]);

  ...

  return (
    ...
    <SearchLocation setWeatherData={setWeatherData} />
    ...
  );
};
```

...

```
function SearchLocation({ setWeatherData }) {
  const [text, textChange] = useState('');

  const handleText = (e) => {
    textChange(e.target.value);
  };

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      "https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json",
      {
        params: {
          key,
          q: text,
          lang: 'en',
        },
      }
    );
    setWeatherData(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      // Only request weather data if `text` is truthy
      if (text) {
        fetchData();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [text]);

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input
          onChange={handleText}
          className="locationInput"
          type="text"
          value={text}
          required
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried to implement this solution to my code and now I have 400 API request failed error. Also whenever react rerenders my inputs in the component it returns undefined. Any other advice regarding them?

Comment: @BerkePalamutcu I see. It looks like 400 errors are related to the `q` parameter. Do you have the specific error code? I see that as-is, the `useEffect` hook will be called on the initial render cycle with the empty string `text` state, so you likely want to conditionally make the GET request ***only when*** `text` is truthy. I'll update. Can you clarify the issue with the inputs for me?

Comment: GET https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=946cb26e574944edb81221535220604&lang=tr 400 and Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16:1)
    at settle (settle.js:17:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js:66:1) I have these errors. I tried to edit q parameter and gave it a sample string and tried to console.log. Result was undefined.

Comment: @BerkePalamutcu Error is `{ "error": { "code": 1003, "message": "Parameter q is missing." } }`. I added a `q=seattle` parameter then receive a code 2006 api key error. Think you could standup a *running* codesandbox demo of your code that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: code: 1003, message: "Parameter q is missing." in the network section also I have this error. I think there is a issue with the q parameter as the child component is responsible for rendering the input text in the main parent app component. I think q parameter needs to be transferred to the app component after every rendering. Maybe the issue is that?

Comment: @BerkePalamutcu I don't think so. The child `SearchLocation` component as the `text` state ***and*** is making the weather api request, it has all the data it needs to make the request, and is passing the response value in a callback back to the parent component. I think you might've moved the wrong part of the code. Can you either update your question to add what you are currently trying to do, or the sandbox?

Comment: okay I will try to sandbox the new changes and update my question. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions to your problem:-

1. Firstly you can create the states `const [text, textChange] = useState('');`
   `const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState([]);`, inside your parent component and pass `text`, `textChange`, `weatherData`, `setWeatherData` as props to your child component.
2. I would recommend the second way, i.e, implement redux for this and store text, and weatherData into your redux and try to access them from redux.

redux reference:- https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Comment: I tried to follow first solution as I am a newbie but when I moved them to the parent component I get textChange is not a function error also API requests are returning with 400. How can I solve them after passing the states as props to the child component?

Comment: When you pass textChange from parent component then you have to use `this.props.textChange()` because now it is a props